# C# Thread.Sleep executing at the wrong location

Tags: c#, multithreading, sleep

I have the following code in C#:

```
if (flag)
{
  SendDataToExternalDevice();
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delayValue);
}

SendMoreDataToExternalDevice();
```

It is very important that *SendDataToExternalDevice()* be executed *delayValue* milliseconds before *SendMoreDataToExternalDevice()*. But it appears that at runtime the program first waits for *delayValue* milliseconds and then runs *SendDataToExternalDevice()* right before *SendMoreDataToExternalDevice()*. Why is this? And how can I resolve this issue?

PS. The wait time doesn't have to be exact within the millisecond (within a second or so is fine), but I don't want the two function to run right after one another.

MORE INFO:
I modified the code to this:

```
if (flag)
{
  for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
  {
     SendDataToExternalDevice();
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }
}

SendMoreDataToExternalDevice();
```

The result of the new code is the following:

SendDataToExternalDevice() called first time

Waiting for 1 second

SendDataToExternalDevice() called second time

Waiting for 1 second

SendMoreDataToExternalDevice() called

So this seems to be working fine. But when I run the original code with a *delayValue* of 2 seconds, it does this:

wait for 2 seconds

SendDataToExternalDevice()

SendMoreDataToExternalDevice()

Comment: Is there more than 1 thread? BTW, what value are you assigning to the delayValue?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful, No there is only one thread.

Comment: What does `SendMoreDataToExternalDevice()` do? How are you measuring?  You might just be seeing buffering.

Comment: Does it use internal buffers? Did you try to flush the stream in SendDataToExternalDevice?

Comment: if `SendDataToExternalDevice` is in your source code, It would be better that you make it async. For example you can raise a ready event when it finishes.

Comment: You could just use a Timer object which is thread safe. And handle your logic above in its elapsed handler.

Comment: @Arash are you sure `flag` is true ?

Comment: @PaRiMaLRaJ, Yes it is true because my program is stalling for the delayValue period so the Thread.Sleep is being reached.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful. Typical *delayValue* is one to a few seconds (1s ~ 10s)

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Thanks. I am passing in milliseconds, so typical values I'm passing are 1000 up to 10000.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a different kind of workflow patter.

```
AutoResetEvent _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(true);

public void SendDataToExternalDevice()
{
    // do some work;


    // release the lock.
    _waitHandle.Set();

    // may be some more work to do
}

public void SendMoreDataToExternalDevice()
{
    _waitHandle.WaitOne();
    // maye be wait addtional time here  ?

    // do send data;
}
```

and here is how you handle your processing

```
if (flag)
{
    SendDataToExternalDevice();
}
SendMoreDataToExternalDevice();
```

Comment: Thanks. It would be much more preferable if I don't have to modify *SendDataToExternalDevice()* and *SendMoreDataToExternalDevice()*. I do have access to this code and can change it if I absolutely have to but that would mean I have to change a whole bunch of other code that is related. Is there no easy way in C# to tell the compiler to tread Sleep as a truly sequential process? Don't optimize or anything just run the thing as you see it?

Comment: yes, there is, make those methods async! and execute it using the async features, although it would use threads but the code will be sequential.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code works the way it does (sounds strange, but `Thread.Sleep` is a complicated beast), and probably can't find out without seeing a lot more of your solution.

In the meantime, can you do something like:

```
int delay = 0;
if (flag)
{
  SendDataToExternalDevice();
  delay = delayValue;
}
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ => SendMoreDataToExternalDevice()
      ,null
      ,delay
      ,Timeout.Infinite);
```

At least to test if it works?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use full memory fences as follows in order to avoid compiler optimizations:

```
if (flag)
{
  Thread.MemoryBarrier();
  SendDataToExternalDevice();
  Thread.MemoryBarrier();
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delayValue);
}
SendMoreDataToExternalDevice();
```

But it feels like somewhere there is a design flaw in your solution.